# how to get gridview selected column

Tags: c#, asp.net

Work on asp.net C# vs05.window platform i can save value on **Tag** property.How can i use this property on web?By using the tag property ,i can easily get the selected row.code snipt

```
class name object = (className)listviewName.SelectedItems[0].Tag;
```

i want to get my gridview selected row value in a **object** like the above .How to get it?

Comment: It is very unclear whether you really mean asp.net - is that a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

```
     // Get the selected row from the GridView control.//

        GridViewRow selectRow = AuthorsGridView.SelectedRow

      //If the first column is, for example, LastName ...//

        String lastName = selectRow.Cells[1].Text;
```

[GridViewRow on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.aspx)